# How can I get a sender's phone number using GSMComm?

Tags: c#, sms

I'm using GSMComm to send and receive SMS messages from Clients of our Company and I was just wondering if there was any way of getting the phone numbers of people who have texted the Program back?

I haven't managed to find an answer on google, also the documentation is a little obscure so I thought I'd search here for an answer.

Any help would be most appreciated =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GsmComm.GsmCommunication` namespace there should be `SubscriberInfo` class that has property `public string Number` that should do it.

https://github.com/welly87/GSMComm/search?q=SubscriberInfo

Answer (score 2):

The `SmsDeliverPdu` class has the `OriginatingAddress`. What you need to do is to parse the `SmsPdu` class object to `SmsDeliverPdu` as

```
DecodedShortMessage[] messages = comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, PhoneStorageType.Sim);

   foreach (DecodedShortMessage message in messages)
       {

           SmsPdu rawmsg = message.Data;
           SmsDeliverPdu msg = (SmsDeliverPdu)rawmsg;
           string message = msg.UserDataText;
           string sender =  msg.OriginatingAddress;

        }
```